# TortoiseSVN Reports an error file foo.c "is locked outside of the working copy"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This problem has been solved. I didn't find any description of this particular problem and am posting the problem description and resolution for other people to reference.

On SVN Commit TortoiseSVN reports the error

> "file foo.c is locked outside of the working copy"

I have not encountered this error message (no error code given) from subversion before.  No information was given by the error message regarding what type of lock was occurring.

SVN Cleanup did not resolve the problem.

Comment: If this problem has been solved, the way to post it on StackOverflow if to put the question and then answer it yourself in a response and accept it. That way it indicates to the system that the question has been resolved.

Comment: This is a question and answer site. If you want to share your information, post the problem in the form of a question (with details), and then post the solution as an answer, just like you'll see in every other post here. Self-answering is acceptable (even encouraged), but please do so properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: The problem was solved by breaking the existing lock.

The first thing I tried was using SVN Cleanup, but that did not resolve the problem.

Looking for SVN Locks on the file using TortoiseSVN->Check for modifications, and selecting "check repository" revealed that the user had the files locked.

Answer (score 0):

Run

> svn cleanup

first and if it will not solve the problem then run same cleanup to root directory.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. In the end the problem was resolved by running break lock. It is confusing that Subversion talks about two different kinds of locks... SVN Unlock/Lock and file-system lock files while an SVN operation is in-progress.